# How can I attach two different meteor.js files?

Tags: meteor

I have two different files of meteor.js running on two different localhosts. How do I integrate both of them?

I created two apps say app1 & app2. On a click of a button in app1,I want to redirect to app2. NOw I want to link both of them.. HOw do I do that. ?

Comment: what do you mean? two different meteor app?

Comment: I created two apps say app1 & app2. On a click of a button in app1,I want to redirect to app2. NOw I want to link both of them.. HOw do I do that. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if you really need two meteor instances,
then they will run on different ports.

so, to link from one to the other you would need to include the port in the link,
so if app2 is on port 3001 and you want to access a page named "pagelink":

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:3001/pagelink">link</a>
```

should do the magic for now.

later you will have to replace the ip and port with the domain of app2

but i would really rethink your concept,
i am pretty sure that you can build all functionality into one meteor instance.

this will also redirect your client to app2 completely, which will cause a page reload AND lose all session data AND reopen a new socket connection AND connect to a different mongodb AND lose the user login AND reload your html templates AND ...

have fun

jascha